# IE9 strange line in asp:textbox

Tags: asp.net, html, css

So I have normal HTML table and inside it I have textbox.

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" CssClass="edit_mode_textbox" />
```

When I lower the textbox width, it's fine, but is there another solution? 
This is only in IE9 and IE8.

Thanks!

[image: strange line]

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could post the generated html and css that applies to it. As well as perhaps seeing if you can recreate the issue in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Your server-side source code is NOT helpful is answering this question. Show the OUTPUT.

Comment: show us your html source code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `asp:textbox` or `Table`, its something wrong with background  image you have set for this `asp:textbox` in your CSS. It may be repeating or you have been using 2 images in background. I am not certain about it unless you paste your CSS class `edit_mode_textbox`.

I hope this will answer your question, if yes please mark it as "answered".

Comment: It was background image used only in IE. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

apply css to remove some styles you do not need:

`box-shadow:0;`, `border:none;` and `borde-radius:0;`